How do I set attributes for all images in a site
I'm having CLS issues and I think I need to set the height/width attributes across all images. Whats the best way to do this?
Is there a CSS code? Where should it be placed?

Are these images in design elements of your theme, and all about the same size? In which case you can probably fix the sizes with CSS yes. Or are they inline images in your articles of different sizes? Then you'd probably need to regenerate the image tags in the articles with the heights and widths there. How did these images end up without heights and widths? I thought WordPress added these automatically.

I think you can use a plugin for optimization like WP Rockert or Perfmatters.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
